# Replacing ceiling vent cover

Tags: ceiling, vent, cover

I need to re[place the ceiling vent cover but the screw holes of the new cover Do Not line up. One screw goes into the existing hole but the other screw only will go into the drywall and then it hits the metal. Can I drill a new hole and if so what am I drilling into? The Metal Chase? Is that OK?

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely hitting the metal flange around the vent that is used to secure the vent to the studs.  If this is what you are hitting, it will be right behind the drywall, then drilling a new hole for the screw is the right action.